# Scope not updated in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, scope, angularjs-directive

I have just started using AngularJS. I've done the tutorial from the official site.
I tried to start my own web application.

I would like to "**resize**" and "**cut**" a `div`.

I started by trying resize `div` but the problem is the `scope` is never updated on `mouse move`. When I mousedown on `div.tool` (red div). I created a directive named `resize direct`.

I don't understand why my scope is not updated.

**Edit : My `scope` is updated in the `console.log(...)`, but not in the view `index.html`**

Thanks

[image]

Here is my code :

**index.html :**

```
<div class="roadmap" ng-app="dragApp" ng-controller="dragCtrl">
<div class="time">
  <div class="duree" resizedirect ng-style="{ width: myWidth }">
     <div class="tool"></div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

**js/directives.js :**

```
'use strict';

var dragDirectives = angular.module('dragDirectives', []);

dragDirectives.directive('resizedirect', function() {
return {
restrict: 'A',
link: function(scope, element, attr) {
  scope.name = "Third ";
  scope.myWidth = "100px";

  var resizer = element.find(".tool")[0];
  console.log(resizer);
  resizer.addEventListener('mousedown', scope.initDrag, false);

  var startX, startY, startWidth, startHeight;

  scope.initDrag = function(e) {
     startX = e.clientX;
     startY = e.clientY;
     startWidth = parseInt(element.css("width"), 10);
     resizer.addEventListener('mousemove', scope.doDrag, false);
     resizer.addEventListener('mouseup', scope.stopDrag, false);
  }

  scope.doDrag = function(e) {
     //console.log( (startWidth + e.clientX - startX) + 'px' );
     startWidth = parseInt(element.css("width"), 10);
     scope.myWidth = (startWidth + e.clientX - startX) + 'px';
     scope.myWidth = "200px";
     console.log(scope.myWidth);
  }

  scope.stopDrag = function(e) {
      resizer.removeEventListener('mousemove', scope.doDrag, false);    
      resizer.removeEventListener('mouseup', scope.stopDrag, false);
  }

}

}
})
```

**js/app.js :**

```
'use strict';

var dragApp = angular.module('dragApp', [
  'ngRoute',
  'dragDirectives'
]);
```

Comment: @zeroflagL: This is probably the right answer, but maybe you need to add an answer with a little more detail. Someone not familiar with the concept is unlikely to be able to guess what they should do by this cryptic "You forgot `$apply()`" message. You should explain what the problem is and give more details on how to solve it (e.x. why is `scope.$apply()` required, where to put it etc).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expressions like `{ width: myWidth }` are evaluated whenever the scope is updated. When you update the scope within an event listener, then you know, but angular does not know that the scope has been changed.

In order to tell angular that the scope has been changed you need to call `scope.$apply()` after the change. This tells angular that something has changed and the expressions might need to be evaluated again.

```
scope.doDrag = function(e) {
  //console.log( (startWidth + e.clientX - startX) + 'px' );
  startWidth = parseInt(element.css("width"), 10);
  scope.myWidth = (startWidth + e.clientX - startX) + 'px';
  scope.myWidth = "200px";
  scope.$apply();
```

Comment: And bim ! Thank you very much. It works great ! I didn't know that angular does not know that has been changed within an event listener.

Answer (score 0):

```
var resizer = element.find(".tool")[0];
```

This doesn't work. From the [docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element):

> find() - Limited to lookups by tag name

You can use this instead:

```
var resizer = element.children()[0]
```

But I think it would be best if you create the div in the directive:

```
var resizer = angular.element('<div class="tool" />');
element.append(resizer);
```

Comment: But if jquery is included then the dependency from jqLite shifts to jQuery and the find method will work as expected, otherwise find is limited to lookups by tag name.

Comment: It works because in the console.log my scope is updated. Not in the view... :(